returning specific generic type based on constraint
I have a method that is giving me a compile error as follows:
interface INoun {}
class Person : INoun {}
class Place : INoun {}
class Thing : INoun {}

enum NounType { Person,Place,Thing }

//...

List<T> GetListOfNouns<T>(NounType type) where T : class, INoun {
  switch (type){
    case NounType.Person:
      return new List<Person>();
    case NounType.Place:
      return new List<Place>();
    case NounType.Thing:
      return new List<Thing>();
    default:
      throw new Exception("NO!!!");
  }
}

The compiler complains that it cannot convert from a List<Person> to a List<T>.  How do I resolve this issue?  Is the only solution an explicit cast?

      return new List<T>();
  }
}```

This is known as the covariance problem. List<INoun> items = new List<Person>() is not valid, because looking at the left side, items allows you to .Add(new Place()), but the backing storage (right side) would not allow you to since it only accepts Person. On the other hand, IEnumerable<INoun> stuff = new List<Person>() is valid, because you can't add anything to stuff that would violate the backing storage.

The error for this code should be "Cannot implicitly convert type 'List' to 'List'", obviously you did not provide the actual code.

@shingo actually what I didn't provide was a copy-pasted error message, and rather typed it out myself, because the error message is simply a tooltip in the editor and not copyable.  Don't be snarky. Sorry I made a typo.

@mjwills what exactly are you trying to say here?

What would you expect to happen if you did List<Person> people = GetListOfNouns<Person>(NounType.Thing);? I would do everything based on T to avoid such conflicts. The enum is extraneous baggage that's only going to complicate things.

I gave you code that does exactly what you want. Unless I am missing something?

The original error message you provided was "to List", which IMO means that the return type of the method was List<INoun> and the type parameter T was not used, which is a big difference rather than a typo. However the enum is declared as NounTypes but used as NounType, this is a typo. As mentioned in the previous comments, this enum and the type parameter are mutually exclusive and should only be kept one.

@ewok — “...because the error message is simply a tooltip”. Sorry, I hardly can believe that. Nearly all IDE and debugging systems let you copy both compiler error messages and exception information to publish it precisely. What are you using for the development?

@mjwills — I posted my answer and only later noticed that you said nearly the same in your comment. Why you did not post it as an answer? However, I can see that ewok did not get it. I don't think you were missing anything. In my answer, I tried to explain things in more details, but I'm not sure it can help. :-(

@NPras — Yes, covariance problem. But I have to add: in this case, it makes no sense to solve this problem. Please see my answer — I credited your comment.

@itsme86 — Yes, exactly, this is the conflict, and it is not resolvable. You are perfectly right about doing everything based on the generic type parameter. Please see my answer. I credited your comment, of course.

Why you did not post it as an answer? Because it seemed a little too obvious. :)

Sure, it does not cast implicitly, but you also don't need an explicit cast.
Essentially, all your method GetListOfNouns does is
System.Collections.Generic.List<T> GetListOfNouns<T>()
   where T: class, INoun =>
        new System.Collections.Generic.List<T>();

But, to do that, you don't even need to create this method. :-)
You can simply use the constructor directly, as the last line of this code sample shows.
As I can see, you did not understand what mjwills wrote. I'll try to explain some more.
Your enum type NounType and the attempt to use it are redundant. The generic type T already carries the information on the actual runtime INoun type. Moreover, the value of the method parameter NounType type could contradict the generic parameter. Say, you could try to call GetListOfNouns<Person>(NounType.Place). It looks like this is the contradiction commented on by itsme86. At this point, you should see that the problem is not the compiler error, but your entire idea and your self-contradicting method profile.
Even if you could somehow solve the covariance problem (see the comment after NPras), it would be pointless and not maintainable. Every time you create a new implementation of the interface INoun, you would need another case in your case statement. No, it would not be acceptable.
I want to credit mjwills, NPras, shingo and itsme86 for correct comments.
